# Why electricity does not seem to alter metal mirrors reflection?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, reflection, metals

If individual electrons absorb and reflect photons, and if those electrons happen to be on a conduction band which is most probable as the outer electrons have a greater probability of intercepting photons first, a voltage applied along the surface of the mirror should displace these electrons and induce visible effects.

Comment: *should displace these electrons and induce visible effects* why do you think this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

The equations of electromagnetism are linear and the response of materials is also predominantly linear. Therefore a static field will not affect reflection. Nonlinear effects do exist but these are generally weak.

Comment: I thought QM existed.

Answer (score 2):

If you think in the frame of reference of the moving electrons, then all that has changed is the direction of the light by an extremely tiny amount (electrons moving slow compared to speed of light), so the reflectivity doesn't change much. This skips over a lot of detail but it is worth thinking about

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary values of voltage probably have such visual effects, but too minuscule to observe. The only case I know of where voltage could influence reflectivity enough is when the resulting electric current is so high that the metal increases its temperature. With different temperature, the metal will have different reflectivity, and another visual effect will appear - the metal will glow with its own light.